# How can I shoot a time-lapse using a Samsung point and shoot camera?

Tags: point-and-shoot, timelapse, wifi, samsung

I have a samsung wb50f point and shoot digital camera. It has wifi remote triggering, but it takes only one image at a time. I want to shoot a time-lapse, which takes photos automatically at a set interval.

Please advise what software could do so either over wifi or USB.

Answer (score 1):

Since your camera doesn't have an external port for an intervalometer nor does any external software currently support the intervalometer function on your series of cameras, the answer is simple: **you can't**.

Answer (score -2):

Since your camera does not come with built-in time-lapse feature, you could invest in an intervalometer. Connect your camera to intervalometer and configure it for time-lapse shoot. Here is a [hackday](http://hackaday.com/2008/07/09/intervalometers-and-timelapse-photography/) on intervalometer. There are more such examples for point and shoot, if you can google them. Good luck with time-lapse..its a cool thing.

HTH